# How to copy Azure Cosmos DB stored procedure using Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-powershell

- I have two different resource groups in Azure portal,
  say **rg-swm-develop** and **rg-swm-production**

  - In both resource groups I have a Cosmos DB account, say **cdb-swm-develop-001** and **cdb-swm-production-001**
  - Both accounts contain the database **admin**
  - The admin database has collections : **names** , **address** , **city**
  - I want to copy a stored procedure from **cdb-swm-develop-001** into **cdb-swm-production-001**

How can I copy the entire stored procedure from one resource group to another using **Powershell**?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Powershell CosmosDB module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/CosmosDB/1.0.8.91). It brings two particular commands that could help you out:

- **Get-CosmosDbStoredProcedure** - to get SP you want to copy a body from
- **New-CosmosDbStoredProcedure** - to create SP in the target account